# Can't open file 'audioAnalysis.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyaudioanalysis

I'm trying to store MFCC feartures of an audio file to a csv file. I'm following the [wiki on github](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki/3.-Feature-Extraction#single-file-feature-extraction---storing-to-file) for Feature Extraction using [pyAudioAnalysis](https://pypi.org/project/pyAudioAnalysis/).
The suggested command is:

```
python3 audioAnalysis.py featureExtractionFile -i test.wav -mw 1.0 -ms 1.0 -sw 0.050 -ss 0.050 -o data/speech_music_sample.wav
```

I'm using the command with minor changing i.e., I'm using python in command as I have only python-3 installed on my PC.

I'm getting an Error:

> C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'audioAnalysis.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

**Please Help!**

Comment: Have you tried passing the full path to your file ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

that the file doesn't exist in your `CWD` or is not set in path. I am assuming that you haven't added your file to the path.

So simply add it to [PATH](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables) on `Windows`. After that you can try:

```
python `C:/pathToFolder/prog.py`
```

or go to the files directory and execute:

```
python prog.py
```

You can also provide a full absolute path to execute it, e.g.

```
python3 <FullAbsolutePath/audioAnalysis.py> featureExtractionFile -i test.wav -mw 1.0 -ms 1.0 -sw 0.050 -ss 0.050 -o data/speech_music_sample.wav
```